# How to save pymongo field result as string

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I'm new to pymgono and I'm trying to understand how to process results. I have the following code inside my Client class which inserts documents in a localhost mongodb:

```
def InsertUser(self,
               userName: str,
               userDescription: str,
               userImage: str):
    # attempt to create or connect to users collection

    aUser = {"image_id": userImage,
             "name": userName,
             "description": userDescription}
    # insert randomly generated document into the database in the reviews collection
    result = self.myCollection.insert_one(aUser)

    print('Created:', aUser)
    print('at collection:', self.myCollection)
    print('with result:', result.inserted_id, '\n')
```

I then fetch specific fields using this method

```
def FindUser(self,
                 userName: str):
        print('found the following users named:',userName,'\n')
        myList=list()
        for i in self.myCollection.find({'name': userName},{'_id':0,'description':1}):
            myList.append(i)
        print('counted numbers in list=',len(myList))
        length=len(myList)
        for i in range(length):
            print(myList[i])
```

The find method prints myList[i] results as following:

```
counted numbers in list= 1
{'description': 'this is my description:'}
```

But what I really want to do is directly insert the description field into separate variable 
in string format like so:

```
counted numbers in list= 1
this is my description
```

How do I do that? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I've given you an answer with some assumption, If it's not the case & you've multiple user documents with same `userName` then you can `descriptionString = myList[i]['description']` & `print(descriptionString)` would give you what you want :-)

Comment: Thank you, this works exactly as I wanted it to and I can iterate more than one field.

Comment: *I can iterate more than one field* ?? Do you get multiple documents ? you're iterating on multiple documents not on multiple fields in a document..

Comment: Actually I do both. I now use print(myList[i]['description'],myList[i]['image_id']) to get both the description and the image_id field (not to be confused with the actual _id field of the document). Is it perhaps a bad practice?

Comment: So you shouldn't iterate on `find_one` & on `find` you can iterate on docs..

Comment: Can you please be a little more specific? How do you iterate on docs and what would you gain from doing so?

Comment: with `find` you're already iterating on an array of docs to access each document seperately !! what I meant is you can not iterate on `find_one` as it would return a dict not an array.. So are you getting any errors or everything running good ?

Comment: Find works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correct userName should be unique for every user document in users collection, then using `.find()` would result in a single document in array, So instead of using `.find()` & iterating on it to get first document out of it, you can use [.find_one()](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html) which would either return a single matched document or `none` if nothing matches with given filter :

```
def FindUser(self,
             userName: str):
    print('finding the following user named:', userName, '\n')
    dBUserResp = self.myCollection.find_one({'name': userName}, {'_id': 0, 'description': 1}):
    if dBUserResp:
        print(dBUserResp.description)
    # Above will return a string 'this is my description:'

    if not dBUserResp:
        print('No user found in DB')
```

**Note :** I had given only positive scenario where you get a result out of DB operation but in general you need to edit your code to check for any error with DB calls itself..

*(Or)*

If it's not the case & if you've multiple user documents with same `userName` then you can do :

```
descriptionString = myList[i]['description']
print(descriptionString) # which prints the description as string
```

Comment: When I try to use this it drops an error "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'description'. I'm using python 3.6

Comment: @MichaelEffraimidis : What are you trying to do ? Are you iterating on result of `find_one` ? Can you give me your current code..